# shrink background-image

Tags: css, background-image

I have a transparent PNG that is used as a picture frame, and I want to utilize the background-image declaration to place an image in the transparent center of the frame.  The problem is that the images I'm using in the background need to be shrunk a bit to fit all of the image's content into the available frame area.

I don't think there is a css or html solution, can I use javascript, jquery, or perhaps php to dynamically shrink the background images to a certain with on load?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS-2 does not support scaling of background images.